# Why doesn't my jQuery respond to window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, jquery-events

I'm using jQuery to add some make some elements on a page transition (via the [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) plugin) when hovered upon. Since I'm trying to design responsively, I want these transitions to only happen when the browser is a certain size or larger.

I've written the following code as an attempt to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $window = $(window);
    var $logo = $('.logo');
    
    function checkWidth() {
        windowsize = $window.width();
    }
    
    checkWidth();
    
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
    
    if (windowsize >= 768) {
        $logo.hoverIntent(
            function(){
                $logo.transition({
                    perspective: '600px',
                    rotateY: '-10deg'
                });
            },
            function(){
                $logo.transition({
                    perspective: '600px',
                    rotateY: '0deg'
                });
            }
        );
    }

});
```

If I load the page in a large browser, it works as expected--the hover effect is active. If I resize the browser, making it smaller (past the breakpoint) and refresh, then it works--the hover effect is disabled. But if I resize the window without refreshing in between, then the effect doesn't respond--it either remains disabled (if resizing from a small to a large screen) or active (if resizing from large to small).

It's a minor quirk, to be sure, but I can't exactly figure out why it's happening. As far as I can tell, when the window resizes, it *should* be updating the `windowsize` variable, which *should* be checked in the `if` statement. What am I overlooking that makes this not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `checkWidth` currently does is assign a value to `windowsize`. You need to move the code that actually reads `windowsize` into `checkWidth`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $window = $(window);
    var $logo = $('.logo');

    function checkWidth() {
        windowsize = $window.width();

        if (windowsize >= 768) {
            $logo.hoverIntent(
                function(){
                    $logo.transition({
                        perspective: '600px',
                        rotateY: '-10deg'
                    });
                },
                function(){
                    $logo.transition({
                        perspective: '600px',
                        rotateY: '0deg'
                    });
                }
            );
        }
    }

    // can trigger the resize handler instead of
    // explicitly calling checkWidth()
    $(window).resize(checkWidth).resize();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

I tried using the code you provided. Now, if I load the page in a small browser, there's no hover effect, and if I make the browser larger without refreshing, the hover effect appears. This is good! However, going large-to-small doesn't disable the hover effect. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: That would be because (**surprise!**) the code does nothing to disable the hover effect when the window size is < 768. You'll have to add code to do that.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Figures I'd overlook something simple like that. Thanks!