# Responding to window resize with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `<header>` and `<nav>` blocks that are affected by JavaScript. What I would like is for the `<nav>` block to become `position: static` if the user resizes the window to smaller than 1119px wide. The script currently works only on page load, but does not detect resize.

I've tried applying the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537714/why-doesnt-my-jquery-respond-to-window-resize), but with no luck. Here's a link to the webpage in question:

http://alookat.org/resize-js/

Here's my JavaScript so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $window = $(window);


    function checkWidth() {
        windowsize = $window.width();

        if (windowsize > 1119) {
           $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(this).scrollTop()>119)
                {
                    $('header').fadeOut();
                    $('nav').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                }
                else
                {
                    $('header').fadeIn();
                    $('nav').css({position: 'absolute', top: 'auto'});
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $('nav').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
        }
    }

    // can trigger the resize handler instead of
    // explicitly calling checkWidth()
    $(window).resize(checkWidth).resize();
});
</script>
```

Comment: `windowsize = $window.width();` try adding `var` before `windowsize`.

Comment: and move the function in global scope outside of doc ready handler.

Comment: Seems more like a job for CSS media queries to me. Kind of pointless to do this in JS. At least the > 1119 part. The scrolling part will still need to be handled in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) for this:

```
$(window).resize(checkWidth)
         .trigger('resize');
```

Try following **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmhLP/)**. When you open console try to resize window in console log should be outputed when ever you resize it.

Try this code in your server:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $window = $(window);

    $window.on('resize', function () {
        windowsize = $window.width();

        if (windowsize > 1119) 
        {
            $window.scroll(function() {
                if ($(this).scrollTop()>119)
                {
                    $('header').fadeOut();
                    $('nav').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                }
                else
                {
                    $('header').fadeIn();
                    $('nav').css({position: 'absolute', top: 'auto'});
                }
            }).scroll();
        }
        else 
        {
            $('nav').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
            $('header').fadeIn();
            $window.off('scroll');
        }
    }).resize();

});
```

**[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/kW9p8/5/show/light/)**

Comment: I can see the message in the console, which is great. The functionality of the JavaScript is the same as before though—it breaks if I resize from 1119px wide or wider downwards and then scroll. I've added a link to the [actual webpage with the code in context here](http://alookat.org/resize-js/) so you know what I mean. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you add `debugger;` inside of your `checkWidth` function for testing purpose?

Comment: Do you want to do something [like](http://jsfiddle.net/kW9p8/5/embedded/result/) this? If it does what you want just let me know I will update my answer accordingly. Or if you want some addition put here you comments.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. Works great. Thanks so much! Legend!

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries in CSS (add somewhere in css)

```
@media (max-width: 1119px) {
  nav {position: 'static' !important; opacity: 1 !important;}
}
```

You can simplify your js

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>119) {
            $('header').fadeOut();
            $('nav').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
        } else {
           $('header').fadeIn();
           $('nav').css({position: 'absolute', top: 'auto'});
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

The scroll function will still execute, but will not make any visual changes. This is good, because it will keep track of the changes and resizing after scrolled down will react properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with the media query (even with the `!important;`) is that the JavaScript overrides it. I've uploaded a [proper webpage with the code](http://alookat.org/resize-js) to make it easier to understand.

Comment: I think you missed `!important` for `nav`. Also i see there is a mistake in my code '.nav' should be 'nav'

Answer (score 0):

Your current code only runs once when the document loads. You need to use something like:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
// your code here

});
```

So you `bind` to the `$(window)`

Comment: This is really close. Thanks for your help. A problem with this code though is that the browser (Chrome, Safari) almost crashes if I spend too long resizing (I think it's checking and noting different window sizes lots of times a second). I also want to retain the ability to check the screen size on page load, as well as page resize.   [Here's a link to the actual webpage with the original code to make it easier to understand the problem](http://alookat.org/resize-js/). The page breaks if I resize from 1119px wide or wider downwards and then scroll.